# Why is Django migration not migrating table?

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

My django migration is not working properly. Out of three models I altered one model(table) in the initial version of my app and ran the makemigrations and then the migration command but the migration for that particular table did not happen properly so I thought there was some problem with the app. I deleted the table from the database and also created a new app and copied all the code from the first app to this one (including the code in the models, views, etc.). But when I use the migration commands, I still do not see the table in the database.

The code for the models is as below

```
class Questions(models.Model):
questionid = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
questiontitle = models.CharField(max_length=50, default = "Title awaited")
questiontxt = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
ans1 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
ans2 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
ans3 = models.CharField(max_length=150)
qcreate_date = models.DateTimeField(default =timezone.now())
is_published = models.BooleanField(default = True)
published_date = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.now(), blank = True)


def _str_(self):
    return self.questiontitle

def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('Question List')


class Answers(models.Model):
userid = models.Integerfield()
questionid = models.IntegerField
userid = models.IntegerField
ans1 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank = True)
ans2 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank = True)
ans3 = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank = True)
anspublished_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now())

The messages I get upon running 
 python manage.py makemigrations 
 python manage.py migrate

I am posting the relevant error message

Migrations for 'qanda':
qanda\migrations\0005_auto_20200503_1342.py
- Alter field anspublished_date on answers
- Alter field published_date on questions
- Alter field qcreate_date on questions 

  Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, contenttypes, qanda, sessions
  Running migrations:
  Applying qanda.0003_auto_20200503_1331...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\admin67\Anaconda3\envs\django2\lib\site- 
  packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 86, in _execute
  return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  psycopg2.errors.UndefinedTable: relation "qanda_answers" does not exist

  django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "qanda_answers" does not exist
```

Comment: kindly attach the error message and the model code with your question.

Comment: I have attached the code and the error messages.

Comment: Try deleting qanda.0003_auto_20200503_1331

Comment: tried it nothing worked. I have deleted my database and recreating it and also the app. can you just let me know how to refer to the auth.users user id as a foreign key in another table? I am not getting the syntax

Comment: Try deleting all migration files. You will find them in migration folder of your app